# Why am I not able to filter rows based on date?

Tags: mysql, date

I am trying to apply a filter on dates which is a string type but I am not able to get the desired results.

for eg,
select * 
from table_1
where date between '01-01-2016' and '31-12-2016';

The output to this query also includes results from 2015 and 2013. Why is this happening?

Comment: I am vote to close this question because I believe it is not clear, as you don't provide enough information about your environment in order for people to be able to help you. Please edit your question, adding the relevant information.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example), as this will provide proper scope around what your actual problem is.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because string comparison knows nothing about dates and how they should be compared. Strings are always compared char by char and `31-12-2016` is bigger than `30-12-2019` or `25-12-0000`.

You have to use native DATE or DATETIME types that are timeline and timezone aware and has a number of useful bundled functions.

Comment: An [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0ac350aa31f199c124d5cfe09ac44961)!